# Converting Esri Shapefile to Geojson file

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert

I am trying to convert an Esri shapefile, e.g. wards boundary data, to a Geojson file format.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to describe the platform, the software in use, and what you have tried so far (including whatever error messages you may have received).

Comment: Is Geomedia Geojson something else than http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the open source GDAL tool 'ogr2ogr' to convert a shapefile to geojson format. Example on the command line type:

`ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" geojson roads.shp`

if you have [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) installed. Not sure what you mean by "Geomedia GeoJSON" though.